# httpd Reverse Proxy - Centos 8

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, centos8

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy using Apache2 on a Centos 8 server.

I currently have nextcloud running on this apache server fine. This is hosted on the domain `storage.domain.com`.

I'd like to setup a reverse proxy for the domain `proxy.domain.com` to the port `8181`.

My config currently exists in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d` directoy.

My reverse proxy file (`proxyfile.conf`)is as follows:

```
ServerName proxy.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName proxy.domain.com
  <Location />
     ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8181/
     ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181/
     ProxyPreserveHost On
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

For reference, my nextcloud file (`nextcloud.conf`)is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/
  ServerName  storage.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://storage.domain.com
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000"
  </IfModule>

  <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>

  </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =storage.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The issue currently is when I go to the domain `proxy.domain.com` is that it redirects me to `storage.domain.com`.

I was expecting the page at `127.0.0.1:8181` to load when visiting `proxy.domain.com`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!